# Custom wordpress theme template page is not public

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress. I have made a custom wordpress theme and have added a few page templates to it, that I have used on different pages. Now the issue is that When I deploy the website on the server the the pages are not public (i.e. the user is asked to enter the username and password before he/she can visit the page). Although I have made them public in the edit page section, but they are still not public. When I change the theme and use any of the default WP themes the pages are public. Need some help in this regard.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it works with the default theme and not yours, its definitely a theme issue, do you have a link to your site or a link to the theme you are using?

Comment: And yea I agree with you that its definitely something to do with my custom theme. Probably I am missing a declaration or something to make the theme public or some theme registration something like that.

Comment: i can see all of the site now from your main menu. What pages are not working?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. The issue has been resolved. The page was redirecting if the user wasn't logged-in